# How to use Django model methods in django views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to use Django model method in views.

models:

```
class stores(models.Model):
    """ This is the store model """

    seo_url = models.URLField()                                                          # SEO URL for flipdiscounts.in
    storeURL = models.URLField()                                                         # Store URL
    fallBackURL = models.URLField()                                                      # Fallback URL for couponURL          
    storeDescription = models.TextField()                                                # Store Description
    storeTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                             # All the tags associated with the store
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=30)                                          # Store Name
    storeSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                         # This is the text you see in the URL
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                      # Time at which store is updated
    storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")                                   # Store Image 
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                  # Time at which store is created
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)                                   # Tag Hash for flipdisconts.in
    storePopularityNumber = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES,default=3)      # Store Popularity Number  


    def Store_Tags(self):
        """Method to return tags related to store"""
        return ','.join([t.tagSlug for t in self.storeTags.all()])

    def tagHash(self):
        """Method to get tag hash related to store for flipdiscounts.in"""
        return ','.join([t.hash for t in self.storeTags.all()])

    def store_URL(self):
        """Method to return store URL for flipdiscounts.in"""
        return self.seo_url + _storeURL + self.hash

    def StoreCoupons(self):
        """Method to return coupons related to store"""
        for t in stores.objects.filter(storeName=self.storeName):
            return ",".join([(a.couponTitle) for a in t.coupons_set.all()])

    def StoreCouponsId(self):
        """Method to return coupons ID related to store"""
        for t in stores.objects.filter(storeName=self.storeName):
            return ",".join([str(a.id) for a in t.coupons_set.all()])

    def CouponsCount(self):
        """Method to return coupons count related to store"""
        for t in stores.objects.filter(storeName=self.storeName):
            count = ",".join([str(a.id) for a in t.coupons_set.all()])
            count = count.split(',')
            count = filter(None,count)
            return len(count)

    def StoreImage(self):
        """Method to return store image for admin panel"""
        return '<img src="/store%s" height="150" width="150"/>' % self.storeImage
    StoreImage.allow_tags = True

    def StoreURL(self):
        """Method to return store URL"""
        return '<a href="%(url)s" target="_blank">%(url)s</a>' %{"url":self.storeURL}
    StoreURL.allow_tags = True

    def imageURL(self):
        """Method to return store Image related to store"""
        return  SERVER_ADDRESS + "store%s"  % self.storeImage 

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to control display Behavior of the Model name """
        verbose_name_plural = "Stores"

    def __unicode__(self):
        """Method to display string correctly"""
        return unicode(self.storeName)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.hash = _generateHash()                                                      # Generate Hash for flipdiscounts.in
        self.seo_url = "discounts-in-" + self.storeName.replace(".","-")                 # Generate SEO URL for flipdiscounts.in        
        super(stores, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    




class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """

    seo_url = models.URLField()                                                 # SEO URL for flipdiscounts.in
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                                         # Tag Description
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)                                      # Tag name
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                  # Extra info can be added to the existing tag using this field
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                             # Time at which tag is updated
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                         # Time at which tag is created
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)                          # Tag Hash for flipdiscounts.in

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Custom Save method for tags model """
        self.hash = _generateHash()                                                 # Generate Hash for flipdiscounts.in
        self.seo_url = "coupons-in-" + self.tagSlug.replace(".","-")                # Generate SEO URL for flipdiscounts.in        
        super(tags, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        """Method to display string correctly"""
        return unicode(self.tag)

    def storeNames(self):
        """Method to get store related to tag"""
        for t in tags.objects.filter(tag=self.tag):
            return ",".join([str(a.storeName) for a in t.stores_set.all()])

    def storeHash(self):
        """Method to get store hash related to tag for flipdiscounts.in"""
        for t in tags.objects.filter(tag=self.tag):
            return ",".join([str(a.hash) for a in t.stores_set.all()])

    def tagURL(self):
        """Method to return tag URL for flipdiscounts.in"""
        return self.seo_url + _tagURL + self.hash

    def couponsId(self):
        for t in tags.objects.filter(tag=self.tag):
            for a in t.stores_set.all():
                return ",".join([str(i.id) for i in a.coupons_set.all()])                     

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to control display Behavior of the Model name """
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"
```

How can i use `tags.storeNames()` in my views.py. Can someone please help me

Comment: Why can't you just call it?

Comment: You can call that function on any object instance of class tags.

Comment: tried doing it but got `    tagStoresData = tags.storeNames()
TypeError: unbound method storeNames() must be called with tags instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: Well that is a basic Python error: as Sudipta says, you need to call it on a tags *instance*. This would be clearer if you followed normal Python style and use CamelCase for your class names (and lower_case_with_underscores for your method names).

Comment: can you please help me... I did not know how to do this

Comment: If you don't know how to get an instance from the database, you should go and do the tutorial where all that is explained. It seems unlikely that after having written all the code above you would be unable to work out how to get a model instance, though.

Comment: I have tried this but not working `tagStoresData = tags()
print tagStoresData.storeNames()`

Comment: *Go and do the tutorial*.

Answer (score 2):

This worked :

```
for i in tags.objects.filter():
    print i.storeNames()
```

Thanks guys for your tip...

Answer (score 0):

```
from appname.models import tags

tagObj = tags()
tagObj.storeNames()
```

Comment: @Bartosz that won't work because the methods are expecting to be called on an actual saved instance (they reference various relationships that wouldn't exist in your code).